# Stop 1Password from asking to save username and password after login

Tags: safari, password, safari-extensions

Every time I log in somewhere in Safari, I get the following pop-up from 1Password.

[image: Would you like to save the username and password for this site in 1Password?]

> Create New | Update Existing
>
> 1Password - Save Login
>
> Would you like to save the username and password for this site in 1Password?

This is especially annoying when the login is already saved in 1Password, but for whatever reason is not recognized for this page. Different domain from what is saved, etc.

How can I prevent 1Password from offering to save logins?

Comment: For user names that are from another domain I would edit the entry in 1password for that user/name/original domain and add the new domain as another website

Comment: @mmmmmm yes, I often do that too. Good answer if you want to add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by:

> 1Password > Preferences > Browsers > Autosave

specifically:

> Detect new usernames and passwords and offer to save them
> (except on the following domains)

[image: Detect new usernames and passwords and offer to save them]

Uncheck that box or add domain exceptions. 1Password will then no longer offer to save new username and password credentials.